# Python - split sentence after words but with maximum of n characters in result

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I want to display some text on a scrolling display with a width of 16 characters.
To improve readability I want to flip through the text, but not by simply splitting every 16. character, I rather want to split on every ending of a word or punctuation, before the 16 character limit exceeds..

Example:

```
text = 'Hello, this is an example of text shown in the scrolling display. Bla, bla, bla!'
```

this text shall be converted in a list of strings with 16 characters maximum

```
result = ['Hello, this is ', 'an example of ', 'text shown in ', 'the scrolling ', 'display. Bla, ', 'bla, bla!']
```

I started with the regex `re.split('(\W+)', text)` to get a list of every element (word, punctuation), but I fail combining them.

Can you help me, or at least give me some hints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd look at the [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module:

```
>>> text = 'Hello, this is an example of text shown in the scrolling display. Bla, bla, bla!'
>>> from textwrap import wrap
>>> wrap(text, 16)
['Hello, this is', 'an example of', 'text shown in', 'the scrolling', 'display. Bla,', 'bla, bla!']
```

There are lots of options you can play with in the [TextWrapper](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper), for example:

```
>>> from textwrap import TextWrapper
>>> w = TextWrapper(16, break_long_words=True)
>>> w.wrap("this_is_a_really_long_word")
['this_is_a_really', '_long_word']
>>> w = TextWrapper(16, break_long_words=False)
>>> w.wrap("this_is_a_really_long_word")
['this_is_a_really_long_word']
```

Comment: You are aweseome! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As DSM suggested, look at `textwrap`. If you prefer to stick with regular expressions, the following will get you *part of the way* there:

```
In [10]: re.findall(r'.{,16}\b', text)
Out[10]: 
['Hello, this is ',
 'an example of ',
 'text shown in ',
 'the scrolling ',
 'display. Bla, ',
 'bla, bla',
 '']
```

(Note the missing exclamation mark and the empty string at the end though.)

Comment: Do you want my honest answer? Better not stick with regex :) But thank you anyway.

Comment: @spky: Actually, I agree with you on this :)

Answer (score 2):

Using regex:

```
>>> text = 'Hello, this is an example of text shown in the scrolling display. Bla, bla, bla!'
>>> pprint(re.findall(r'.{1,16}(?:\s+|$)', text))
['Hello, this is ',
 'an example of ',
 'text shown in ',
 'the scrolling ',
 'display. Bla, ',
 'bla, bla!']
```